# Vector to Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen3

I am new using Eigen library and I am having problems transform/reshape a vector in a matrix.

I am trying to get an specific row of a matrix and convert it as a matrix, but each time that I do that the result is not what I am expecting.

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> m(8, 9);
m << 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
     21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
     31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
     41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49,
     51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59,
     61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
     71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79,
     81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89;

std::cout << m << std::endl << std::endl;

Matrix<double,1,Dynamic,RowMajor> B = m.row(0);

std::cout << B << std::endl << std::endl;
Map<Matrix3d,RowMajor> A(B.data(),3,3);   
std::cout << A << std::endl << std::endl;
```

Result

```
11 14 17
12 15 18
13 16 19
```

I want:

```
11 12 13 
14 15 16 
17 18 19
```

Comment: Try `Map<Matrix<double, 3, 3, RowMajor>>(B.data(), 3, 3)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to select a row first and then map. Just map directly from *m* and assign the transpose of map to a matrix A as follows

```
Matrix3d A = Map<Matrix3d>(m.data()).transpose();
```

If you don't like transposing then forcing the map to use *RowMajor* for the destination type works too

```
Matrix3d A = Map<Matrix<double, 3, 3, RowMajor>>(m.data());
```

Although, at this small size it doesn't matter. Cheers

Comment: Thank you, that is the thing. Transpose the matrix doesn't matter for this size of matrix but for big matrix could be an extra step that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the transpose of the result matrix. I think eigen library is converting a vector to a matrix by picking every n'th element to form a row in a n*n sized vector.